# Collection view with estimated item not scrolls after 4-5 cells

Tags: swift

I have a collectionView with estimated size and I am trying to scroll it. But problem is it is scrolling well only 4-5 items, then stops. If I set absolute size of collection view everything is fine. But I have to use estimated cell.

Collection:

```
private lazy var collection: UICollectionView = {
        let collection = UICollectionView(frame: view.bounds, collectionViewLayout: createLayout())
        collection.register(TabsViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: TabsViewCell.reuseIdentifier)
        collection.register(ProductsCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: ProductsCollectionViewCell.reuseIdentifier)
        collection.register(SeriesLabelCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: SeriesLabelCell.reuseIdentifier)
        collection.delegate = self
        
        return collection
    }()
```

Layout

```
 private func newsFilterSection() -> NSCollectionLayoutSection {
        let itemSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .estimated(1),
                                              heightDimension: .absolute(36))
        let item = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: itemSize)
        item.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: 0)
        let groupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .estimated(1),
                                               heightDimension: .absolute(36))
        let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize: groupSize,
                                                       subitems: [item])
        let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: group)
        section.orthogonalScrollingBehavior = .continuous
        section.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 16, leading: 16, bottom: 12, trailing: 7)
        return section
    }
```

I scroll like

```
collection.scrollToItem(at: IndexPath(item: toItem, section: sectionIndex), at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: true)
```

Also I tried methods scrollRectToVisible, scrollToView, nothing helps